# "Invalid image path" error while trying to upload a binary via XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm getting the following error while trying to upload the binary to iTunes Connect:
[image]

Even though the images are specified in the plist:
[image]

They are also added to the project and to the project directory:
[image]

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was solved by pressing "Use asset catalog" in the project menu.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the properties to include file extension - 'logo57.png' etc.